# More ruby-like way of writing simple ActiveRecord code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is some fairly standard Ruby on Rails 4 ActiveRecord code:

```
  def hide(user)    
    self.hidden = true
    self.hidden_on = DateTime.now
    self.hidden_by = user.id
  end

  def unhide
    self.hidden = false
    self.hidden_on = nil
    self.hidden_by = nil
  end

  def lock(user)
    self.locked = true
    self.locked_on = DateTime.now
    self.locked_by = user.id
  end

  def unlock
    self.locked = false
    self.locked_on = nil
    self.locked_by = nil
  end

  # In effect this is a soft delete
  def take_offline(user)
    hide(user)
    lock(user)
  end
```

The code is easy to understand and doesn't try to be clever. However it feels verbose. What would be a more succinct or canonical way of specifying this code/behaviour?

Comment: I'd do it pretty exactly like that, nice and simple and obvious. You could try to get clever with callbacks hooked up to `hidden_by_changed?` and such but that would just spread the logic around and make the code harder to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's a trade-off, but if you want to be more clever, you can do something like:

```
def self.def_toggle(type, field)
  define_method(type) do |user|
    send("#{field}=", true)
    send("#{field}_on=", DateTime.now)
    send("#{field}_by=", user.id)
  end

  define_method("un#{type}") do
    send("#{field}=", false)
    send("#{field}_on=", nil)
    send("#{field}_by=", nil)
  end
end

def_toggle(:hide, :hidden)
def_toggle(:lock, :locked)
```

Comment: This is fairly easy to understand and definitely more extensible

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit extreme unless you have a lot of these or you want to encapsulate a bit more logic. But you can do something like the following using [composed_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html)

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  composed_of :hidden, class_name: 'State', mapping: %w(hidden, hidden_on, hidden_by)
  composed_of :locked, class_name: 'State', mapping: %w(locked, locked_on, locked_by)

  def hide(user)
    hidden.on
  end

  def unhide
    hidden.off
  end

  def lock(user)
    locked.on
  end

  def unlock
    locked.off
  end
end


class State < Struct.new(:state, :on, :by)
  def on(user)
    set(true, user)
  end

  def off
    set(false, nil, nil)
  end

  def on?
    state
  end

  def off?
    !on
  end

  private

  def set(state, by, on = Time.current)
    self.state = state
    self.by = by
    self.on = on
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting approach which is a lot more extensible (e.g. if more fields such as flagged, reviewed, etc are added) than the my original simple solution.